# Set variable group dynamically using System.PullRequest.TargetBranch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to set group dynamically in a pull request pipeline using azure devops. Yaml file looks like as below:

```
variables:
 - ${{ if eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev') }}:
   - group: dev-var-group
```

This does not work and condition is evaluated to 'false'. Just to confirm it I reversed the condition as below

```
variables:
 - ${{ if ne(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev') }}:
   - group: dev-var-group
```

After which group was set correctly and all the required variables are read and pipeline works.

Can anyone please assist here to get this working with the correct condition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible. If you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) at `Template expression syntax`:

> You can use template expression syntax to expand both template parameters and variables (${{ variables.var }}). Template variables are processed at compile time, and are replaced before runtime starts. Template expressions are designed for reusing parts of YAML as templates.
>
> Template variables silently coalesce to empty strings when a replacement value isn't found. Template expressions, unlike macro and runtime expressions, can appear as either keys (left side) or values (right side). The following is valid: ${{ variables.key }} : ${{ variables.value }}.

and to have this working you need a template variable and `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` is rather runtime variable, thus it is replaced to empty string. If you check predefined variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) you will notice last column `Available in templates?`

[image]

which says `no` for `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps would be enough to evaluate Build.Reason as its available in templates?

Also you could check pull request source branch during the runtime and assign variables based on this. I.e.:

```
Write-Host “##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue”).
```